# Exponential fit in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data:

```py
puf = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                    'val':[850,1889,3289,6083,10349,17860,28180,41236]})
```

The data seems to follow an exponential curve. Let's see the plot:

```py
puf.plot('id','val')
```

[image]

I want to fit an exponential curve (`$$ y = Ae^{Bx} $$`, A times e to the B*X)and add it as a column in Pandas. Firstly I tried to log the values:

```py
puf['log_val'] = np.log(puf['val'])
```

And then to use Numpy to fit the equation:

```py
puf['fit'] = np.polyfit(puf['id'],puf['log_val'],1)
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (8)
```

My expected result is the fitted values as a new column in Pandas. I attach an image with the column fitted values I want (in orange):

[image]

I'm stuck in this code. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. How can I create a new column with my fitted values?

Comment: The results you have are from fitting a log- curve and not an exponential curve. You need to state as to whether you want an exponential curve or log-curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting that error because `np.polyfit(puf['id'],puf['log_val'],1)` returns two values `array([0.55110679, 6.39614819])` which isn't the shape of your dataframe.

This is what you want

```
y = a* exp (b*x) -> ln(y)=ln(a)+bx
f = np.polyfit(df['id'], np.log(df['val']), 1)
```

where

```
a = np.exp(f[1]) -> 599.5313046712091
b = f[0] -> 0.5511067934637022
```

Giving

`puf['fit'] = a * np.exp(b * puf['id'])`

```
   id    val           fit
0   1    850   1040.290193
1   2   1889   1805.082864
2   3   3289   3132.130026
3   4   6083   5434.785677
4   5  10349   9430.290286
5   6  17860  16363.179739
6   7  28180  28392.938399
7   8  41236  49266.644002
```

Comment: So the values A and B are 0.5511 and 6.3961?

Comment: From the docs the polyfit gives `Polynomial coefficients, highest power first` for eq `p(x) = p[0] * x**deg`

Comment: This is a different model compared to the question, though might be close.  Note that the question asks to fit `log(E(Y)) = XB` yet you have fit `E(log(Y)) = XB`, which is abit different. Since log is concave we have `log(E(Y)) >= E(log(Y))` So somehow close but not necessarily true

Comment: I calculated the formula in Excel... it seems that the coefficients are A: 599.53 and B: 0.5511, that doesn't match the results you have.

Comment: And that's what I needed! It's not direct to Pandas but it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that you asked for an exponential model yet you have the results for log-linear model.

Check out the work below:

For log-linear, we are fitting `E(log(Y))`ie `log(y) - (log(b[0]) +b[1]*x)`:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
least_squares(lambda b: np.log(puf['val']) -(np.log(b[0]) + b[1] * puf['id']), 
        [1,1])['x']
 array([5.99531305e+02, 5.51106793e-01])
```

These are the values that excel gives.

On the other hand to fit an exponential curve, the randomness is on Y and not on its logarithm, `E(Y)=b[0]*exp(b[1] *x)` Hence we have:

```
least_squares(lambda b: puf['val'] - b[0]*exp(b[1] * puf['id']), [0,1])['x']
array([1.08047304e+03, 4.58116127e-01]) # correct results for exponential fit
```

Depending on your model choice, the values are alittle different.

Better Model? Since you have same number of parameters, consider the one that gives you lower deviance or better out of sample prediction

Note that the ideal exponential model is `E(Y) = A'B'^X` which for comparison can be written as `log(E(Y)) = A + XB`  while log-linear model will be `E(log(Y) = A + XB`. Note the difference in Expectation.

From the two models we have:

[image]

Notice how when we go to higher numbers the log-linear overestimates. While in the lower numbers the exponential overestimates.

Code for image:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
log_lin = least_squares(lambda b: np.log(puf['val']) -(np.log(b[0]) + b[1] * puf['id']), 
        [1,1])['x']
expo = least_squares(lambda b: puf['val'] - b[0]*exp(b[1] * puf['id']), [0,1])['x']

exp_fun = lambda x: expo[0] * exp(expo[1]*x)
log_lin_fun = lambda x:log_lin[0] * exp(log_lin[1]*x)

plt.plot(puf.id, puf.val, label = 'original')
plt.plot(puf.id, exp_fun(puf.id), label='exponential')
plt.plot(puf.id, log_lin_fun(puf.id), label='log-linear')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you onyambu, I guess my take is wrong and your answer is clear!